# LaTeX prehistory

Tags: tex-history, latex-2.09

I came into LaTeX in the 80s and my copy of *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System* already described LaTeX 2.09. I'm curious if anyone here knows about the versions of LaTeX that preceded that. What changed between LaTeX 1.x and LaTeX 2.0, or between 2.0 and 2.09? I suspect that much of this knowledge has disappeared along with the am* fonts or the various VMS-CHANGE and CMS-CHANGE files I worked on back in the day (or my horribly inefficient DVI viewer for VM/CMS, which, perhaps, is best lost in the ether).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

https://www.latex-project.org/get/#historic-latex

links to various ancient versions, I think the oldest I have seen is

```
% LATEX VERSION 0.9 - FOR USE WITH TEX VERSION 0.95
\immediate\write10{
LATEX Version 0.9 - for use with TeX version 0.95
}
```

http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/macros/latex-saildart/latex-0.90/